# Installing PHP7 and Apache2.4 - php7apache2_4.dll error on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, apache

Just got on a Windows 10 and after I configured my php.ini and http.conf I went on the command line `httpd.exe` and got this error message:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 530 of C:/Apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

I KNOW this file is in that folder. I've installed both 64 bits version of PHP and Apache and I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 34):

Check whether you have installed Thread safe version of PHP. Non Thread safe version will cause this error.

You can download thread safe version of PHP [here](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.1)

Comment: Not necessarily. I did download the thread-safe release, I restarted Wamp, and I am still getting this error. The only benefit of the later release to me was to ship with that DLL, whereas the NTS release didn't ship with it.

Answer (score 5):

while you downloading PHP u should select ThreadSafe pack, Apache not supporting nonThreadSafe...

Comment: [About](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php/) thread-safe in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

As the others said, the NON Thread safe (nts) does not support apache and u have to install thread safe versions

Answer (score 0):

Which VC compiled version of Apache do you use?
On [php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/) they recommend to use the apache server from [apachelounge.com](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) combined with the threadsafe php files.
Also make sure that you have installed the C++ Redistributable Visual Studio 2015.
If it still fails with that error make sure the user who is starting the process has access to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this error by uninstalling my previous version of wampserver , then installing the latest version (3.2.0), closer to the php7.4.9 target.

As I previous had php 7.2 with an earlier version of wampserver (can't remember which), none of the above tricks would work for me. I was still getting the error of this topic title. **Now working ok**.

***Reminder**: to integrate an external version of php into wamp, rename php.ini-development in folder php7.4.9 into phpForApache.ini*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but I had an issue that the Apache httpd service would not start when I tried to add the php module to an apache server (httpd.conf).  The service would not start. When I looked at the Event Viewer I found an application error event indicating that the service terminate unexpectedly, and it indicated that the problem occurred in Apache24\bin\libapr-1.dll.

The problem was with the LoadModule statement that I added at the end of my httpd.conf file.  Here's what I orginally had:

LoadModule php7_module "C:\PHP7\php7apache2_4.dll"

Here's what I changed it to:

LoadModule php7_module C:\PHP7\php7apache2_4.dll

Low and behold, the apache service started, any I was able to execute the phpinfo.php sample script that I added to the Root Document directory.  (By the way, forward or backward slashes both work.)

The difference is that I removed the quotes. The quotes were there because I had just copied and pasted from a web page that said how to install PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and when i looked in the apache24 error log it said something about PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown etc. I had installed a version of vcredist but obviously it needed a more upto date version and found solution here: [vcruntime140.dll 14.0 not compatible with PHP build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414170/vcruntime140-dll-14-0-not-compatible-with-php-build)