# 'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16

Tags: php, visual-c++, installation

[image]

I'm trying to get PHP 7.4.1 (NTS x64, Zip version) to run on my Windows development machine, but I'm getting the following output in my run window in PhpStorm:

```
C:\path_to_php\php.exe -S localhost:80 -t C:\path_to_my_project\www
[Tue Dec 31 15:42:39 2019] PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've done some research on the problem and found [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414170/vcruntime140-dll-14-0-not-compatible-with-php-build) that suggests installing the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 found [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#file-format-x64-129729). I installed the latest x64 version and restarted my computer but to no avail, I still get the exact same error message. I have also tried running the installer *again* and done a repair+restart, but that didn't help either.

Running `php -i` in the command line works flawlessly, and displays the configuration info for PHP 7.4.1, which is the same PHP instance I'm trying to run in PhpStorm.

The same problem occurs with PHP 7.4, but PHP 7.3 works like a charm.
I'm at a loss. Has anyone had the same problem, and found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I had `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable` installed alongside `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable`. When I uninstalled the 2017 version, PHP started playing nicely. Hope this helps people in the same situation!

Answer (score 4):

As @Daniel Opitz commented on 14th Jan, the problem was, that PhpStorm is getting shipped with an *old* or *wrong* version of `vcruntime140.dll`.

To fix this error I had to :

1. open the directory C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.3.1\jbr\bin and
2. then renamed the file `vcruntime140.dll` to `vcruntime140.dll.old`
3. Restart PhpStorm

It works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I am using XAMP and the below worked for me

I renamed the file `vcruntime140.dll` to `vcruntime140_old.dll` under the folder

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had this problem for months now. I listen to this simple comment, it works. Can't believe that. lol

Answer (score 0):

php needs The latest supported Visual C++ to run.
I solved the problem in my pc by downloading The latest supported Visual C++. here is the link[latest supported Visual C++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)

Answer (score 0):

I am using XAMPP and the below worked for me
without installed any version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable

I renamed the file `vcruntime140.dll` to `vcruntime140_backup.dll` under the folder

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

second thing is go to this folder path for example `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` search for the same file `vcruntime140.dll`

copy & paste into this folder path:

```
 C:\Windows\System32
```