# Why is this error showing up in command prompt?

Tags: php

So I was following a tutorial on Youtube on getting starting coding php(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK_JCtrrv-c)And I was told to put "php -v" in the command prompt to ensure php was working. When I typed that in, an error message saying "PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0" Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vcruntime140.dll 14.0 not compatible with PHP build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414170/vcruntime140-dll-14-0-not-compatible-with-php-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your php packages is outdated. You can try updating your packages however I think it is unlikely that you will run into any problems. Personally I would ignore this warning. Notice that it is only a "warning" rather than an error. This is quite common.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it was that simple!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this error on [https://www.edopedia.com/](https://www.edopedia.com/qa/questions/30/php-warning-vcruntime140-dll-14-0-is-not-compatible-with-this-php-build-linked)

> Basically, PHP version 7.4.x requires Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019. You can download it from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019) and then simply install it. After that, try to start Apache. Hopefully, this time it will work without any issues.

If you need a step-by-step guide you can use this article on [https://studyopedia.com/](https://studyopedia.com/errors-resolved/fix-php-warning-vcruntime140-dll-not-compatible/)

I hope you find this helpful.