# XAMPP Apache won't open

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have been pulling my hair out for the last hour or so trying to get the Apache service to work for class. I have been running apache-control.exe as an admin and I tried it as both an installed and uninstalled service. I have changed the ports it runs on, I have reinstalled XAMPP many times, and I have reinstalled the Microsoft VCRuntime.

Here is what my error log looks like:

```
[Mon Sep 26 12:52:35.034165 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 5988:tid 352] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Sep 26 12:52:35.088318 2022] [:emerg] [pid 5988:tid 352] AH00020: 
Configuration Failed, exiting
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414170/vcruntime140-dll-14-0-not-compatible-with-php-build. This may help you

Comment: Its a Microsoft C/C++ Runtime Library [Install from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685) Avoid using any other site than a Microsoft site, you might end up with anything

Comment: I had tried reinstalling VCRuntime already. I did it again anyways and still nothing.