XAMPP Apache won't run on windows 11
This is the error message I get:

[ssl:warn] [pid 10708:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0

I've uninstalled and re-installed and I've changed to port number.
I want to run apache from the XAMPP control panel so that I can use WordPress.

The first line is a warning, it shouldn't stop Apache. The second line is a failure, meaning the VCRUNTIME140 does not match and does not work with the PHP build. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414170/vcruntime140-dll-14-0-not-compatible-with-php-build might be of some help

You want to setup a server on the internet based on a MS Windows system? Really?
