# How to set a proper Apache version for PHP 8

Tags: php, apache, wampserver, php-8

I have installed PHP version 8.0.8 and followed [this tutorial](https://www.myonlineedu.com/blog/view/16/how-to-update-to-php-8-in-wamp-server-localhost) to add the new PHP version in Wamp Server.

The tutorial says in `wampserver.conf` file, `LoadModuleFile` is `php8apache2_4.dll`. Except `php8apache2_4.dll` does not exist in my PHP 8 repository. Where can I find/download it ?

Comment: If you have WAMPServer 3 then you can download SIMPLE Addons for all versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL/mariaDB from Sourceforge or better still [the backup repo which is much easier to navigate](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have most likely not downloaded the thread safe version of PHP8. Credit to Kumar for the answer in [this
post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484775/installing-php7-and-apache2-4-php7apache2-4-dll-error-on-windows-10)

Comment: It's the thread safe version. I have tried downloading again and still, the `php8apache2_4.dll` file doesn't exist.

Comment: @lharry was it VS16 x64 Thread Safe (2021-Jun-29 16:38:40)? That zip file includes php8apache2_4.dll https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-8.0.8-Win32-vs16-x64.zip

Comment: You're right. This zip contains the `php8apache2_4.dll` file. Thanks.